# retrição de chave estrangeira incorretamente formada laravel migration

Tags: laravel

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateMenusTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {        
        Schema::create('menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('opcao');
            $table->string('href');
            $table->boolean('session');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('submenu', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('submenu_id')->index;
            $table->foreign('submenu_id')->references('id')->on('menu');
            $table->string('opcao');
            $table->string('href');
            $table->boolean('ligado');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

    }}
```

está a dar erro de restrição de chave estrangeira mal formada.
Alguém me pode ajudar. Este erro ocorre quando executo o comando `php artisan migrate`.

Comment: Cara eu criei a sua migration em uma aplicação que já tenho, e ela rodou normalmente, sem erros. Pode printar o erro que ocorre ou algo assim?

Answer (score 0):

Faltou colocar `unsigned` no `submenu_id` para que a `migration` seja concretizada, porque, a chave primária da tabela `menu` é criado como `unsigned` que significa que o campo só aceite valores positivos, então, o relacionamento também precisa saber disto e configurado para tal. Exemplo:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateMenusTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {        
        Schema::create('menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('opcao');
            $table->string('href');
            $table->boolean('session');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('submenu', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('submenu_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('submenu_id')->references('id')->on('menu');
            $table->string('opcao');
            $table->string('href');
            $table->boolean('ligado');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

    }
}
```